# need smarty function, it will change digit to words

Tags: smarty

I need to display digit as a word in smarty,

ie.,

```
In PHP I pass the value $Rank = 2 to samrty 
by
$smarty->assign('Rank', $Rank);
```

Then, it will be display in samrty as "two".

Any inbuilt function is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function for this.  Though it would be pretty easy to make one.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.tpl